# npm require fails to detect simple-peer module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, p2p

I Have installed the below npm module

```
https://github.com/feross/simple-peer
```

by,

```
#sudo npm install simple-peer -g
```

But When tried including the module, it is unable to find the module. I received the below error

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'simple-peer'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cst/poc/test.js:1:73)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

In my sample code I just had

```
var pee = require('simple-peer');
```

Comment: Don't install it globally, install it locally to your project (in other words, drop the `-g`).

Comment: I tried both the ways still same issue. ;(

Comment: Does `npm ls --depth=0` show it installed locally?  And does `npm ls -g --depth=0` show it installed globally?

Comment: To clarify @JoeClay's comment, you must run the local install command in the project directory.

Comment: Whoops, yeah, wasn't clear about that. Thanks @RyanZim!

Comment: got to your folder and run `npm install --save simple-peer` and it will be okay